# Is the 1990 Australian produced show "Ultraman: Towards the Future" in continuity with the other Ultra series?

Tags: ultra-series

Just managed to find this show, and I remember it [vaguely] as my third or so introduction into the Ultra-verse [saw clips of the original 1960s show as a kid, a version that happened later in the series in the 70s, and an anime in the 80s]. I only remembered it because in 1991, there were a *few* commercials linked to toys for a show which honestly *did not show* on regular TV in New York at the time. Then I came across the SNES game [which was a *poor* fighting game, but allowed me to see the characters outright] and a 1993 comic book series in my local shop which seemed to follow that very same story.

Years later, after being a minor fan of *Ultraman Tiga* and learning more about the still-on-going Ultra series, I was able to follow it due to my love of *Power Rangers* as a fellow *tokusatsu* series. So I was able to follow up on this one; it's a bit ridiculous, and hammy, with a heavy handed environmental message, but it means well, and is not bad for late 80s fun. I'm uncertain if it is in line with the canon of the rest of the series though. Oh, I know it was produced in *conjunction* with the official Ultraman team, of course, but so was *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* and that is not [as of yet] in "canon" with the MCU.

Complicating things further is that back in 2004 there was a major motion picture which basically "rebooted" the series [*Ultraman: The Next*] which basically retold the first Ultraman story in modern times. This movie was sort of meant to "unify" the ultraverse, with a follow up film coming afterwards. I never saw that one, or the subsequent. Nice little trailer here, though:

And, found out later a *new* Ultraman movie, full CGI was meant to come out in 2016. Saw a trailer for that here:

Never followed up on it, though, so I'm not even sure where *this* film sits in canon.

Can anyone clarify if this all takes place in the same universe, please, especially in regards to the 1990 show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultraman Great, the name of the Ultraman who appeared in Ultraman: TtF, was largely a stand-alone show, not referenced in later series.

However in the recent film **Mega Monster Battle: Ultra Galaxy Legends The Movie**, Ultraman Great appeared as one of the member of the defending Ultra Force, as was Ultraman Powered, star of the other English (and largely stand-alone) Ultra Series, **Ultraman the Ultimate Hero**.

[image]

So both series seem to have been officially added to the Ultra-canon.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to clarify things.